# SupportMapFragmentManager not resolving

Tags: android, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

I am trying to create a SupportMapFragment inside a fragment..I get the following error:
`The method SupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MapFragment`

my code is as follows:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment{

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       { 
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_view, container, false);
         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
         DateTimeFragment datetime=new DateTimeFragment();
         ft.add(R.id.datetime_container_map, datetime);
         SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)SupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
         return v;
       }

}
```

However, SupportMapFragmentManager does not resolve. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you added support v4 library ?

Comment: I have added these:
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

Comment: Its actually, com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13744765/507905

Comment: hi, i actually have done that, as you can see in my edited code. Had imported this library earlier. SupportMapFragmentActivity was working when I did extends FragmentActivity..but I wanted to have the map inside a Fragment. That is why I changed it to extends Fragment

Comment: @Ankita posted my answer check it,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to kalyan pvs's answer, your code is wrong, should look like this:

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
```

In your question, you use the method `SupportFragmentManager()` which doesn't exists. 
The method `getSupportFragmentManager` is not available in Fragments, but `getFragmentManager` will work. 
This is I guess, because your class already extends the support version of Fragment and therefore `getFragmentManager` will automatically return the support version of the FragmentManager.

Comment: Hi, I had actually done mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment); in another class that extends FragmentActivity. And it works completely fine. However, it wasn't working when I did extends Fragment. I changed it to what you suggested and it resolved

Comment: I changed my answer a bit. Just use getFragmentManager and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check these couple of answers for the problem similar to yours by CommonsWare. Check [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409263/2003486) and [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16004205/2003486).

Also, make sure you have Android Private Libraries checked under Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export. Then clean the project and check if the issue is solved.